# Ubuntu 18.04 dual iface gateway with no internet activity

Tags: ubuntu, pppoe, shorewall

I'm having trouble getting my two interface Ubuntu Server (18.04) to:

1. have a working pppoe connection to the internet, and;
2. share that connection with the rest of my LAN.

I mention 2. because in the past I managed to get the WAN connection working on the gateway (no idea how), but then the hard drive failed (it was new!!). After the rebuild I can't even get the gateway to have a working net connection. Grrrr

Currently I can conect to my ISP via pon, but then can't do anything with the connection, not even ping 8.8.8.8. I also tried pinging my ISP nameserver with no sucess.

My netowrk architecture is: LAN <--> Gateway interface enp3s0 <--> Gateway (shorewall/routing) <--> Gateway interface ppp0 (tunnelled via ens33) <--> External Modem <--> Internet

I've included the following file contents to (hopefully) diagnose what I'm missing:

- Netplan config
- Result of 'ifconfig'
- pppoe connection log from syslog (for confirmation the connection has been made)
- The result of 'route'
- Contents of resolve.conf
- Shorewall files: shorewall.comf, zones, policy, interfaces, snat and rules

Any advise/solutions are very much welcome. Thanks and merry christmas!

**Netplan:**

```
root@gateway:/etc/shorewall# cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.54.141/24
      gateway4: 192.168.54.141
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
    ens33:
      dhcp4: yes
```

**ifconfig:**

```
root@gateway:/etc/shorewall# ifconfig
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.54.141  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.54.255
        inet6 fe80::226:2dff:fe24:9143  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:26:2d:24:91:43  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6428904  bytes 4050106497 (4.0 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 72  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6303032  bytes 4310814732 (4.3 GB)
        TX errors 4  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18

ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::213:3bff:fe4a:2934  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:13:3b:4a:29:34  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 131934  bytes 21509371 (21.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 47321  bytes 8213015 (8.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2219702  bytes 180229868 (180.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2219702  bytes 180229868 (180.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1492
        inet 86.146.246.68  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 172.16.16.5
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 62  bytes 2737 (2.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3  bytes 54 (54.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**SYSLOG output for pppoe connection:**

```
Dec 25 18:07:16 gateway pppd[8011]: pppd 2.4.7 started by scootyPuff uid 0
Dec 25 18:07:16 gateway pppd[8011]: PPP session is 4206
Dec 25 18:07:16 gateway pppd[8011]: Connected to 24:af:4a:c0:fe:62 via interface ens33
Dec 25 18:07:16 gateway pppd[8011]: Using interface ppp0
Dec 25 18:07:16 gateway pppd[8011]: Connect: ppp0 <--> ens33
Dec 25 18:07:16 gateway systemd-udevd[8012]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Dec 25 18:07:16 gateway networkd-dispatcher[1194]: WARNING:Unknown index 12 seen, reloading interface list
Dec 25 18:07:16 gateway pppd[8011]: CHAP authentication succeeded: CHAP authentication success
Dec 25 18:07:16 gateway pppd[8011]: CHAP authentication succeeded
Dec 25 18:07:16 gateway pppd[8011]: peer from calling number 24:AF:4A:C0:FE:62 authorized
Dec 25 18:07:16 gateway systemd-networkd[29646]: ppp0: Gained carrier
Dec 25 18:07:16 gateway pppd[8011]: not replacing default route to enp3s0 [192.168.54.141]
Dec 25 18:07:16 gateway pppd[8011]: local  IP address 86.146.246.68
Dec 25 18:07:16 gateway pppd[8011]: remote IP address 172.16.16.5
Dec 25 18:07:16 gateway pppd[8011]: primary   DNS address 81.139.57.100
Dec 25 18:07:16 gateway pppd[8011]: secondary DNS address 81.139.56.100
```

**Route:**

```
root@gateway:/etc/shorewall# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.54.141  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp3s0
default         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens33
172.16.16.5     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens33
192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens33
192.168.54.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp3s0
```

**resolv.conf:**

```
root@gateway:/etc/shorewall# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 81.139.57.100
nameserver 81.139.56.100
options edns0
```

**SHOREWALL:**
Version: 5.1.12.2

**shorewall.conf:**

```
root@gateway:/etc/shorewall# cat shorewall.conf
###############################################################################
#
#  Shorewall Version 5 -- /etc/shorewall/shorewall.conf
#
#  For information about the settings in this file, type "man shorewall.conf"
#
#  Manpage also online at http://www.shorewall.net/manpages/shorewall.conf.html
###############################################################################
#                      S T A R T U P   E N A B L E D
###############################################################################

STARTUP_ENABLED=Yes

###############################################################################
#                            V E R B O S I T Y
###############################################################################

VERBOSITY=1

###############################################################################
#                               P A G E R
###############################################################################

PAGER=

###############################################################################
#                            F I R E W A L L
###############################################################################

FIREWALL=

###############################################################################
#                              L O G G I N G
###############################################################################

LOG_LEVEL="info"
BLACKLIST_LOG_LEVEL=
INVALID_LOG_LEVEL=
LOG_BACKEND=
LOG_MARTIANS=Yes
LOG_VERBOSITY=2
LOGALLNEW=
LOGFILE=/var/log/messages
LOGFORMAT="%s %s "
LOGTAGONLY=No
LOGLIMIT="s:1/sec:10"
MACLIST_LOG_LEVEL="$LOG_LEVEL"
RELATED_LOG_LEVEL=
RPFILTER_LOG_LEVEL="$LOG_LEVEL"
SFILTER_LOG_LEVEL="$LOG_LEVEL"
SMURF_LOG_LEVEL="$LOG_LEVEL"
STARTUP_LOG=/var/log/shorewall-init.log
TCP_FLAGS_LOG_LEVEL="$LOG_LEVEL"
UNTRACKED_LOG_LEVEL=

###############################################################################
#       L O C A T I O N   O F   F I L E S   A N D   D I R E C T O R I E S
###############################################################################

ARPTABLES=
CONFIG_PATH=":${CONFDIR}/shorewall:${SHAREDIR}/shorewall"
GEOIPDIR=/usr/share/xt_geoip/LE
IPTABLES=
IP=
IPSET=
LOCKFILE=
MODULESDIR=
NFACCT=
PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin"
PERL=/usr/bin/perl
RESTOREFILE=restore
SHOREWALL_SHELL=/bin/sh
SUBSYSLOCK=""
TC=

###############################################################################
#               D E F A U L T   A C T I O N S / M A C R O S
###############################################################################

ACCEPT_DEFAULT="none"
BLACKLIST_DEFAULT="Broadcast(DROP),Multicast(DROP),dropNotSyn:$LOG_LEVEL,dropInvalid:$LOG_LEVEL,DropDNSrep:$LOG_LEVEL"
DROP_DEFAULT="Broadcast(DROP),Multicast(DROP)"
NFQUEUE_DEFAULT="none"
QUEUE_DEFAULT="none"
REJECT_DEFAULT="Broadcast(DROP),Multicast(DROP)"

###############################################################################
#                        R S H / R C P  C O M M A N D S
###############################################################################

RCP_COMMAND='scp ${files} ${root}@${system}:${destination}'
RSH_COMMAND='ssh ${root}@${system} ${command}'

###############################################################################
#                       F I R E W A L L   O P T I O N S
###############################################################################

ACCOUNTING=Yes
ACCOUNTING_TABLE=filter
ADD_IP_ALIASES=No
ADD_SNAT_ALIASES=No
ADMINISABSENTMINDED=Yes
AUTOCOMMENT=Yes
AUTOHELPERS=Yes
AUTOMAKE=Yes
BALANCE_PROVIDERS=No
BASIC_FILTERS=No
BLACKLIST="NEW,INVALID,UNTRACKED"
CLAMPMSS=Yes
CLEAR_TC=Yes
COMPLETE=No
DEFER_DNS_RESOLUTION=Yes
DELETE_THEN_ADD=Yes
DETECT_DNAT_IPADDRS=No
DISABLE_IPV6=No
DOCKER=No
DONT_LOAD=
DYNAMIC_BLACKLIST=Yes
EXPAND_POLICIES=Yes
EXPORTMODULES=Yes
FASTACCEPT=No
FORWARD_CLEAR_MARK=
HELPERS=
IGNOREUNKNOWNVARIABLES=No
IMPLICIT_CONTINUE=No
INLINE_MATCHES=No
IPSET_WARNINGS=Yes
IP_FORWARDING=On
KEEP_RT_TABLES=No
LOAD_HELPERS_ONLY=Yes
MACLIST_TABLE=filter
MACLIST_TTL=
MANGLE_ENABLED=Yes
MAPOLDACTIONS=No
MARK_IN_FORWARD_CHAIN=No
MINIUPNPD=No
MULTICAST=No
MUTEX_TIMEOUT=60
NULL_ROUTE_RFC1918=No
OPTIMIZE=All
OPTIMIZE_ACCOUNTING=No
PERL_HASH_SEED=0
REJECT_ACTION=
REQUIRE_INTERFACE=No
RESTART=restart
RESTORE_DEFAULT_ROUTE=Yes
RESTORE_ROUTEMARKS=Yes
RETAIN_ALIASES=No
ROUTE_FILTER=Yes
SAVE_ARPTABLES=No
SAVE_IPSETS=No
TC_ENABLED=Internal
TC_EXPERT=No
TC_PRIOMAP="2 3 3 3 2 3 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2"
TRACK_PROVIDERS=Yes
TRACK_RULES=No
USE_DEFAULT_RT=Yes
USE_NFLOG_SIZE=No
USE_PHYSICAL_NAMES=No
USE_RT_NAMES=No
VERBOSE_MESSAGES=Yes
WARNOLDCAPVERSION=Yes
WORKAROUNDS=No
ZERO_MARKS=No
ZONE2ZONE=-

###############################################################################
#                       P A C K E T   D I S P O S I T I O N
###############################################################################

BLACKLIST_DISPOSITION=DROP
INVALID_DISPOSITION=CONTINUE
MACLIST_DISPOSITION=REJECT
RELATED_DISPOSITION=ACCEPT
RPFILTER_DISPOSITION=DROP
SMURF_DISPOSITION=DROP
SFILTER_DISPOSITION=DROP
TCP_FLAGS_DISPOSITION=DROP
UNTRACKED_DISPOSITION=CONTINUE

################################################################################
#                       P A C K E T  M A R K  L A Y O U T
################################################################################

TC_BITS=
PROVIDER_BITS=
PROVIDER_OFFSET=
MASK_BITS=
ZONE_BITS=0
root@gatewst:/etc/shorewall#
```

**rules:**

```
root@gateway:/etc/shorewall# cat rules
# Shorewall - Sample Rules File for two-interface configuration.
# For information about entries in this file, type "man shorewall-rules"
######################################################################################################################################################################################################
#ACTION         SOURCE          DEST            PROTO   DEST    SOURCE          ORIGINAL        RATE            USER/   MARK    CONNLIMIT       TIME            HEADERS         SWITCH          HELPER
#                                                       PORT    PORT(S)         DEST            LIMIT           GROUP
?SECTION ALL
?SECTION ESTABLISHED
?SECTION RELATED
?SECTION INVALID
?SECTION UNTRACKED
?SECTION NEW

#       Don't allow connection pickup from the net
#
Invalid(DROP)   net             all             tcp

# Accept DNS connections from the firewall to the network
# Following line commented out as it's covered by the policy allowing all $FW connection to net zone
# DNS(ACCEPT)   $FW             net
 DNS(ACCEPT)    loc             $FW
 DNS(ACCEPT)    loc             net

# Accept NetBOIS requests from LAN
SMB(ACCEPT)     $FW             loc
SMB(ACCEPT)     loc             $FW

# Accept SSH connections from the local network for administration
SSH(ACCEPT)     loc             $FW

# Accept HTTP connections
HTTP(ACCEPT)    loc             net
HTTPS(ACCEPT)   loc             net

# Allow Ping from the local network
Ping(ACCEPT)    loc             $FW
Ping(ACCEPT)    $FW             net
Ping(ACCEPT)    loc             net

# Drop Ping from the "bad" net zone.. and prevent your log from being flooded..
Ping(DROP)      net             $FW
Ping(DROP)      net             loc

ACCEPT          $FW             loc             icmp
ACCEPT          $FW             net             icmp
```

**zones:**

```
root@gateway:/etc/shorewall# cat zones
# For information about entries in this file, type "man shorewall-zones"
###############################################################################
#ZONE   TYPE    OPTIONS                 IN                      OUT
#                                       OPTIONS                 OPTIONS
fw      firewall
net     ipv4
loc     ipv4
#modem  ipv4
```

**interfaces:**

```
root@gateway:/etc/shorewall# cat interfaces
# For information about entries in this file, type "man shorewall-interfaces"
###############################################################################
?FORMAT 2
###############################################################################
#ZONE   INTERFACE       OPTIONS
net     $NET_IF          dhcp,tcpflags,nosmurfs,routefilter,logmartians,sourceroute=0,physical=ppp0
loc     $LOC_IF          dhcp,tcpflags,nosmurfs,routefilter,logmartians,physical=enp3s0
#modem   $MODEM_IF        dhcp,tcpflags,nosmurfs,routefilter,logmartians,physical=ens33
```

policy:

```
root@gateway:/etc/shorewall# cat policy
# For information about entries in this file, type "man shorewall-policy"
###############################################################################
#SOURCE DEST            POLICY          LOGLEVEL        RATE    CONNLIMIT

loc     all             ACCEPT
net     all             DROP            $LOG_LEVEL

# Allow firewall to talk to internet and LAN
$FW     net             ACCEPT
#loc    $FW             ACCEPT
$FW     loc             ACCEPT

# THE FOLOWING POLICY MUST BE LAST
all     all             REJECT          $LOG_LEVEL
```

**SNAT:**

```
root@gateway:/etc/shorewall# cat snat
# For information about entries in this file, type "man shorewall-snat"
#

# See http://shorewall.net/manpages/shorewall-snat.html for more information
###########################################################################################################################################
#ACTION                 SOURCE                  DEST            PROTO   PORT    IPSEC   MARK    USER    SWITCH  ORIGDEST        PROBABILITY
#
# Rules generated from masq file /home/teastep/shorewall/trunk/Shorewall/Samples/two-interfaces/masq by Shorewall 5.0.13-RC1 - Sat Oct 15 11:41:40 PDT 2016
#
MASQUERADE              10.0.0.0/8,\
                        192.168.54.0/24         $NET_IF
```

Comment: Hmm. Do you have packet forwarding enabled? Check /etc/sysctl.conf for net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 . I would also suggest taking a look at the [ars technica router guide](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/04/the-ars-guide-to-building-a-linux-router-from-scratch/) - [my own build](https://journeymangeek.com/?p=196) is a spin on that though I use firewalld and dnsmasq. Are you using static IPs on clients?

Comment: Packet forwarding is enabled. Double checked /etc/sysctl.conf anyway. I'm meant to be behind a dynamic IP, but my ISP doesn't seem to have changed it in a while.

Comment: Oh client side. I see no mention of a DHCP server

Comment: I am running my own DHCP server for my LAN. It's bound to the LAN interface port and works just fine, serving IPs from 192.168.54.150 up. IP below are reserved for things I want a static IP for (routers, servers, etc). My netplan file states no DHCP on the LAN interface (enp3s0) as I want an internal static IP for my server. Interface enp3s0 is dynamic and gets its IP from the external modem's DHCP server. The setup tutorials I used said this was the thing to do and allowed my ISP to grant my pppoe IP address.

Comment: Ah ok. Hmm.how does a traceroute out from your network to 8.8.8.8 look?

Comment: also looking at my setup - try removing the gateway4: 192.168.54.141
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4] stanzas. I'm pretty sure I had a netplan config here somewhere... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061276/ubuntu-server-18-04-1-netplan-and-ufw seems reasonable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the advice everyone. After more 'hacking' and illimination I found the answer.

There were a twoissues:

1. Despite defining the various options in Shorewall for start on boot, it wasn't. Turns out I needed to define a systemd service script for it. That answer came from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shorewall/+bug/1511869/comments/3).
2. I was getting in a real mess with the nameserver IP popping in and out of existance in /etc/resolv.conf AND the default routes. I don't fully understand what was going on, but its probable I was getting my knickers twisted with all my experimenting. I didn't investigate the truth behind that fully, but what I did do was to implement an rc.local script the removed all default routes, then re added the correct route. So now when I do a "ip route show" the correct route is first on the list.

With that all in place I can now reboot the server and have the gateway automatically back up with no intervention/modification. PHEW!

Thanks for you advice & patience!